# PHP Search: Using Jquery to alter a php a value

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a comics website. A feature it has is to allow users to search comics... the search will instantly parse the input and return thumbnail results based on matching title and keywords.

Originally, the search would return all of the results, and the bounding search box would expand infinitely downward, holding every single comic result. I thought it may be a nice touch to limit the results to 4, and display a message like "load 5 remaining images" if the user chooses to do so.

If they click on that message, I wanted limiting php variable to be removed or changed.

So far, it loads with the limit, and shows a link...

[image]

**EDIT: Latest Code:**

**search_field.php (the search file that get's included on a page... this file calls search.php via JQuery):**

```
<?php $site = (isset($_GET['site']) ? ($_GET['site']) : null); ?>

<div id="sidebar" class="searchborder">
<!--Allow users to search for comic-->
<!--<span class="search">Search for <?php// echo (($site == "artwork") ? 'artwork' : 'a comic'); ?> </span>-->

<script type="text/javascript">

    function GetSearch(mySearchString){
     $.get("./scripts/search.php", {_input : mySearchString, _site : '<?php echo $site ?>'},
            function(returned_data) {
                $("#output").html(returned_data);
            }
        );

    }

</script>
<center>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>

                <span class="search">
                <img src="./images/SiteDesign/Search.png" />
                    <input type="text" onkeyup="GetSearch(this.value)" name="input" value="" />
                    <!--<input id="site" type="hidden" value="<?php// echo $site; ?>">-->
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</center>
<span id="output">  </span>

 </div>
```

---

**search.php, the file that's called to parse the string and return the results:**

```
<?php
//Query all images:
include 'dbconnect.php';


$site = $_GET['_site'];
$input = (isset($_GET['_input']) ? ($_GET['_input']) : 0); 
$siteChoice = (isset($_GET['_choice']) ? ($_GET['_choice']) : $site);
$start = (isset($_GET['_start']) ? ($_GET['_start']) : null);

echo "start: " . $start;


//if user goes to hittingtreeswithsticks.com... no "site" value will be set... so I need to set one
if ($site == null) {
$site = "comics";
}

if ($siteChoice == "artwork") {
$sql = "SELECT id, title, keywords, thumb FROM artwork";
$thumbpath = "./images/Artwork/ArtThumbnails/";
}
else if ($siteChoice == "comics") {
$sql = "SELECT id, title, keywords, thumb FROM comics";
$thumbpath = "./images/Comics/ComicThumbnails/";
}
else {
$sql = "SELECT id, title, keywords, thumb FROM $site";
if ($site == "artwork") {
    $thumbpath = "./images/Artwork/ArtThumbnails/";
}
else {
    $thumbpath = "./images/Comics/ComicThumbnails/";
}
}
/* For this to work, need all comics replicated in an "All Comics" file along with "All Thumbnails"
else {
$sql = "SELECT id, title, thumb FROM comics 
        UNION 
        SELECT id, title, thumb FROM artwork";
$thumbpath = "./images/AllThumbnails/";
}*/


$imgpaths = $mysqli->query($sql);
mysqli_close($mysqli);

$idresult = array();
$imgresult = array();
$thumbresult = array();

//CHECK IF $INPUT == IMAGE PATH
if (strlen($input) > 0)
{
while ($row = $imgpaths->fetch_assoc()) 
{
    //query against key words, not the image title (no one will remember the title)
    if (stripos($row['keywords'], $input) !== false || strtolower($input)==strtolower(substr($row['title'],0,strlen($input))))
    //if (strtolower($input)==strtolower(substr($row['title'],0,strlen($input))))
    {
        array_push($idresult, $row['id']);
        array_push($imgresult, $row['title']);
        array_push($thumbresult, $row['thumb']);
    }
}   
//ECHO RESULTS ARRAY 
if(count($imgresult) == 0) 
{
    echo "<p>no suggestions</p>";
}
else 
{

    echo "<ul>";
        $k = 0;
        $max = 4;
        if (count($imgresult) > $max) {
            while ($k < count($imgresult) && $k < $max)
            {
                echo '<li>
                        <span class="sidebarimages"><a href=".?action=viewimage&site=' . $siteChoice . '&id=' . $idresult[$k] . '">
                        <img src="./scripts/thumber.php?img=.'.$thumbpath.$thumbresult[$k].'&mw=90&mh=90"/></a></span>
                      </li>'; 
            $k++;
            }
            $difference = count($imgresult)-$k;
            echo "<br/><i><a href='.?action=homepage&site=" . $siteChoice . "&start=4'  class='loadSearch'>load " . $difference  . " more result" . (($difference != 1) ? 's' : '') . "... </a></i>";
        }
        else {
            while ($k < count($imgresult))
            {
                echo '<li>
                        <span class="sidebarimages"><a href=".?action=viewimage&site=' . $siteChoice . '&id=' . $idresult[$k] . '">
                        <img src="./scripts/thumber.php?img=.'.$thumbpath.$thumbresult[$k].'&mw=90&mh=90"/></a></span>
                      </li>'; 
            $k++;
            }
        }




    echo "</ul>";
}
}
?>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(".loadSearch").click(function() {

//alert("Test");

$.get("./search.php", {_start : 4}, 
    function (returned_data) {
        $("#moreResults").html(returned_data);
    }
);


});
</script>
```

Comment: hummm jQuery isotope plugin will help...http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

Comment: @DipeshParmar that's pretty awesome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with jquery show and hide functions.

**PHP Snippet:**

```
//ECHO RESULTS ARRAY 
if(count($imgresult) == 0) 
{
    echo "<p>no suggestions</p>";
}
else 
{

    echo "<ul>";
        $k = 0;
        $max = 4;

            while ($k < count($imgresult) && $k < $max)
            {
                echo '<li>
                        <span class="sidebarimages"><a href=".?action=viewimage&site=' . $siteChoice . '&id=' . $idresult[$k] . '">
                        <img src="./scripts/thumber.php?img=.'.$thumbpath.$thumbresult[$k].'&mw=90&mh=90"/></a></span>
                      </li>'; 
                $k++;
            }

            $difference = count($imgresult)-$k;

            echo '<div id="moreResults">';
            while ($k < count($imgresult))
            {
                echo '<li>
                        <span class="sidebarimages"><a href=".?action=viewimage&site=' . $siteChoice . '&id=' . $idresult[$k] . '">
                        <img src="./scripts/thumber.php?img=.'.$thumbpath.$thumbresult[$k].'&mw=90&mh=90"/></a></span>
                      </li>';

                $k++;
            }
            echo '</div>';


        if (count($imgresult) > $max) {
            ?>
            <br /><a href="#" id="showMore">Load <?php echo $difference; ?> more result<?php echo (($difference != 1) ? 's' : ''); ?>...</a>
            <?php
        }

    echo "</ul>";
}
}
```

**Jquery:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#moreResults").hide();

$("#showMore").click(function() {
    $("#moreResults").show();
    $("#showMore").hide();

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$("#loadSearch").click(function() {
    $.get('URL WITH QUERY', function(data) {
        $('#results').html(data);
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: for the $.get, is it possible to load a php function from within this same file? Or do I need to load a separate php file?

Comment: no jQuery can't call a php function because it's client side and php is server side

Comment: Okay, so do I have to create a new php file just so I can call it with $.get?

Comment: No you just call the same php file with a different limit this time

Comment: 1) How would I call the same file, 2) How can I change the limit within the file? Should I pass different parameters from the $.get request to the file and just use those?

Comment: I don't understand why $.get("./search.php", {_start : 4}... wouldn't send "_start" to back to the php file once the load more link is clicked on (< a href='.?action=homepage&site=" . $siteChoice . "&start=4' class='loadSearch'>load more</a>)

Comment: Yes just load the file again with a different query

Comment: Okay, I have search_field.php, which has the input field on it... on key up it will call jquery $.get and send the search parameters to search.php php code to parse the input string (the code you see above)~ is my $(".loadSearch").click(function() { code that's supposed to be within my search.php file, and just recall the file that it's within ($.get("./search.php", {_start : 4},...) or should this be in the search_field.php file?

Comment: No your url should look something like "./search.php?start=5"

Answer (score 1):

From what i get all you need is when "load more" is clicked only new results should be shown.

Load more has to be a url same as your search url.

```
Search/Autocomplete URL - example.com/autocomplete?q=xkd
Load More URL - example.com/autocomplete?q=xkd&start=4&max=1000
```

Just add two parameters to your url. `start and max`. Pass them to your queries and you get exact result.

Only verify `Start < Max` and are integers `intval()` and not 0 `empty()`. Also if `Max <= 4` then dont show load more.

Comment: I've edited my post above... can you elaborate? Which URL am I adding these parameters to?

Comment: Hi, I've updated my answer above, would something like that work? I should pass in those parameters using jquery $.get command, right? Or should I just pass them directly in the load more URL?

Comment: And using jquery, as I have above, I should only need to pass in that additional single parameter for the new start location ($start), right? Because the $input has already come in from the original search

Comment: yes... everything now happens on server-side. You only need to pass $start for subsequent queries

Comment: Okay, I've just updated my code above to include everything... I honestly don't see what I'm doing wrong.. when I click the "load more" link, it just refreshes the page...

Comment: I don't understand why $.get("./search.php", {_start : 4}... wouldn't send "_start" to back to the php file once the load more link is clicked on (< a href='.?action=homepage&site=" . $siteChoice . "&start=4'  class='loadSearch'>load more</a>)

Comment: @Growler add  to your click event on load more "return false"

Comment: I just realized adding the parameters like you suggested won't work. The search box is in a file called search_field.php, which I include on homepage.php. search_field.php has jquery which sends a $.get to the server and passes the search string to be parsed into search.php... search.php then responds to by echoing out the result... which is picked up by search_field.php ($("#output").html(returned_data);)... which is shown on homepage.php.

Answer (score 1):

I would give all of your results back, then try to determine your results. If more then 4, loop out the first 4 results. If the user clicks on the load more button your start looping from your 4th element. That way you only need to hit the server once (per search).

Try to give back your results in json, so you can format it the way you like in your html file.

In pseudo code:

```
searchTerm = 'hello';
resultsFromServer = getResults($searchterm);
resultcounter = count(resultsFromServer);

if(resultcounter > 4)

   loop 4 results

else

   loop all results


$(".loadSearch").click(function(e) {

//alert("Test");

e.preventDefault();

$.get("./search.php", {_start : 4}, 
    function (returned_data) {
        $("#moreResults").html(returned_data);
    }
);
```

Comment: If they click on "load more", how would I start looping again from the 4th element?

Comment: Also, what should the loadmore link look like? Where should it link to? After doing your idea, I still have the "load more" link as:    if (count($imgresult) > $max) {
    echo "<br/><span id='loadSearch'><i><a href=''>load " . $difference  . " more result" . (($difference != 1) ? 's' : '') . "... </a></i></span>";
   }

Comment: You could keep track of a counter (do a count of your elements and then with a for loop, read them) the load more I would add it in your javascript if you see that there are more then 4 elements.

Comment: So you're saying... if there are more than 4 elements, load the rest of those into a javascript array... and then loop through the javascript array to ouput the remaining items?

Comment: you got them already in an array (because you do your request and get back ALL the matching items). So you need to loop out the rest :)

Comment: Okay, I've just updated my code above to include everything... I honestly don't see what I'm doing wrong.. when I click the "load more" link, it just refreshes the page...

Comment: I updated my post. try the e.preventDefault(); that way the page doesn't get refreshed.

Comment: That doesn't work... Now instead of refreshing the page, the link does nothing.

Comment: I don't understand why $.get("./search.php", {_start : 4}... wouldn't send "_start" to back to the php file once the load more link is clicked on (< a href='.?action=homepage&site=" . $siteChoice . "&start=4' class='loadSearch'>load more</a>)